# Errors while using psutil to profile a Windows batch script launched using psutil.Popen(command)?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, psutil

I am trying to use PSUtil to profile various processes launched by using `psutil.Popen(command)` until those processes terminate.

On Linux I can use this approach to profile just about anything, and on Windows I can do this to profile .exe commands. However, if I try to profile a .bat file (which itself kicks off other executables), it launches the batch script but doesn't profile anything.

Note that on Linux if uses this approach to profile something like a bash script, all the processes the script spawns will be profiled as though they were part of the parent script. Windows batch scripts, on the other hand, do not exhibit such behavior when profiled. Is there any way to get psutil to act this way when launching Windows batch scripts?

Comment: Provide a sample batch file and Python script that uses psutil to profile it.

Comment: In general the problem may be that Windows doesn't keep a process tree. It has to be built from a snapshot by looking at the parent PID of each process. If one process in the chain has already exited, the missing link splits the tree.